# Importing a specific folder from a GIT Erlang repository in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, intellij-14

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2
Erlang plugin 0.11.1144
SDK: Erlang OTP 25, erts-13.0
Folder To be Imported: https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/master/lib/common_test
```

I am able to import the complete project https://github.com/erlang/otp.git in IntelliJ. But, I am interested in a specific module [common_test](https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/master/lib/common_test). I checked File->New->ProjectFromVersionControl, but did not find any option to clone a specific folder. Does IntelliJ support such cloning? Please let me know the procedure if available.

One option could be to clone the specific folder outside IntelliJ as explained in [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951) & then import it using File->New->ProjectFromExistingSources in IntelliJ.

[image: Get From Version Control]

Answer (score 2):

With Git, cloning a specific folder is a bit tricky. In fact, you can't clone only the folder, as you clone the entire repository.

What you can do is actually to use partial-clone in combination with sparse-checkout git features. See [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

These options are currently not supported in IJ UI, unfortuantely